# hosting administration system?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

i'm looking for an opensource system to manage a list of web hosting clients.

- Services ordered
- payment notifications
- ticket support system

That kind of stuff

Is there anything like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're asking, probably Freeside.

- http://www.freeside.biz/freeside/

I've not used it, but I have heard some nice things said about it by smaller groups.

If memory serves there are at least a couple more in PHP, but I'm not sure about the features:

- CitrusDB always seemed a bit plain, but it's there -> http://www.citrusdb.org/
- AgileBill has also had some nice things said about it, but provides no demonstration -> http://www.agileco.com/agilebill-open-source-billing-software.htm

jBilling ( http://www.jbilling.com/ ) is also opensource with a commercial alternative (apparently with the same functionality).

Comment: thanks Swixel

Well i've been using AgileBill for a while, but is a pain to translate it to spanish (my system must be in spanish) and it's quiet old in its marckup.

I will give a try to CitrusDB and freeside.

Thanks again mate!

Comment: Not a problem.  I've been noticing that most of the older software isn't so friendly to translate (hard-coded text!), and the stuff I've used has always been 'heavier' (Python or JSP), resulting in most of the software being relatively difficult to access.  Might be time for some coding over this short break ;)